# Why does React warn against an contentEditable component having children managed by React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the following warning when rendering my component:

> Warning: A component is `contentEditable` and contains `children`
>   managed by React. It is now your responsibility to guarantee that none
>   of those nodes are unexpectedly modified or duplicated. This is
>   probably not intentional.

This is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Editable extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div contentEditable={true} onBlur={this.props.handleBlur}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What is the potential problem with my code that React wants to warn me about? I did not quite understand from reading the documentation at https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html.

I imagine that my component should work exactly like an managed input field, without any problem:

1. `this.props.children` is initial value
2. the `onBlur` callback updates the props from `event.target.innerHTML`
3. the component is rendered with the new props

Comment: React is warning you against using a potential footgun. If you know how to properly handle the tool so that it doesn't shoot you in the foot, then run with it. If you manage to shoot yourself in the foot, don't be surprised, because you were warned.

Comment: React doesn't know what is contained in `this.props.children`, it only knows that you can destroy those props. There are consequences for all sorts of things. If there are event subscriptions, they could become memory leaks, if there are bound properties they could become danglers, etc. As zzzBov said, don't shoot yourself in the foot. It doesn't sound like you will, but neither React nor we can know that.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Setting the `contenteditable` html attribute allows the contents of that element to be modified in the browser. React is warning you that you have children within that element that are managed by React. React only works from the top down. Meaning it manages a model at the top level and maintains a virtual DOM representing that data, then renders the DOM tree based on that virtual DOM. Any changes you make to the DOM outside of React (such as setting `contenteditable` and allowing the content to be edited by a user directly in the browser) will be potentially blown away or cause problems for React when it goes to update those managed elements.

In your situation you don't care that the `{this.props.children}` node gets blown away because you know you're catching the changes and doing what you need to with it. It's just warning you that you better not expect that node to remain intact and accurately updated by React when you're letting the content be edited by the browser directly.

If you know what you're doing (and for now it looks like you do) then you can suppress that warning by adding `suppressContentEditableWarning={true}`.

Comment: Hi @Chev, thanks it works !! but I am curious to know the disadvantage also, suppressing the error. However, just avoiding the error doesn't promise that everything is working fine on page.

Comment: The disadvantage would be that you might forget and get stuck wondering why user content is getting destroyed. No suppressing the error doesn't promise everything is working fine. Understanding the error does. And in your case you're not doing anything that would run into problems with this because you're only using `this.props.children` to set the component's initial value.

Comment: @Chev could give a simple example as to when we can run into problems?

Comment: More recently, jsut use the bare suppressContentEditableWarning keyword.

Comment: @oyalhi Very late reply here lol . Anything more than an initial value would be an issue. Especially if you put other React components within the content-editable element.

Answer (score 22):

Thanks @Chev! It fixed the warnings..

```
      <p
        className={editing ? 'editing' : ''}
        onClick={editOnClick ? this.toggleEdit : undefined}
        contentEditable={editing}
        ref={(domNode) => {
          this.domElm = domNode;
        }}
        onBlur={this.save}
        onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
        {...this.props}
        suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
      >
        {this.props.value}
      </p>
```

Comment: @isherwood he is a question author

Comment: @Vadim, that doesn't change the fact that this answer is not a self-contained solution. Please see [answer].

Comment: @isherwood the author wanted to post code to show the fix and help others. You can't post code in comments. The overpolicing on SO is not helpful and plays right into the toxic reputation of this site.