# React.js: Getting "Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a `<span>` element that is inside of a contentEditable `<div>`. In certain situations, when I try to delete everything in the `<div>` at once with `Command-Delete`, or when I try to delete individual characters from the `<span>` element when it is the only thing inside of the `<div>`, I get the error in the title.

How can I go about fixing this?

I put together a sandbox example of the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-wildflower-52eul?file=/src/App.js

It throws the error under two circumstances (the keyword in the example is `test`, it should get highlighted in blue when you type it):

1. Type any string with `test` inside of it or just `test` and highlight everything and delete.
2. Type any string with `test` inside of it, delete everything else except for `test`, then delete any character in `test`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Codesandbox supports JSX and React. Go to https://codesandbox.io/index2 create a new one from the React template and edit your question with a minimum example. I'm happy to help afterwards!

Comment: Hi @RodrigoEhlers, just put together a sandbox of the issue, thanks!

Comment: @JasperHuang did this issue get fixed, i am also facing the same error intermittently with draftjs

Comment: @orangespark I ended up scrapping the idea altogether since it was causing too many issues; sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most probably read the following error when you set `contentEditable` of your `div` to `true`:

```
Warning: A component is `contentEditable` and contains `children` managed by React. It is now your responsibility to guarantee that none of those nodes are unexpectedly modified or duplicated. This is probably not intentional.
```

The problem here is that you let React add a child node to the content editable `div` and remove it through the actual DOM when interacting with it and removing all of its content.

React tries to re-render, and remove the `span` that should not be existent on **next render** however, you already removed it through your keyboard input.

You should only suppress the warning if you're absolutely sure about what you're doing, as it is warning you about the exact error you're getting.

The solution you're going for will not work as you would like it to.

You could be better off trying to implement an edit mode and highlighting the words after the user saves the content. This is only an idea as I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve.

More info on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49639256/7381466

Answer (score 2):

Just give the key to the parent element i.e div className='app ' according to your code or add a new parent element and just give the key to that element.

and if anything changes and you get this error, just update the key of the parent element

Because updating that parent element key causes react to detach the parent element from its dom, you can avoid this error because the problem is with the child element.

In onInput just check if the elemeent with  id="addItemInput" is present or not and if it is not there just update the parent element key