# How to apply this functionality without refs and DOM manipulation

Tags: reactjs

Since refs are discouraged, is there any way I can apply the functionality below with state or some other way?

```
saveAfterEdit = () => {
  //some code
  document.getElementById(id).contentEditable = 'false';
}

edit = () = > {
  document.getElementById(id).contentEditable = 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just like any other attribute, so you specify this as a prop:

```
<div contentEditable={this.state.editable} />
```

This said, there are other concerns with using `contentEditable` in a React context that have nothing to do with altering the prop. There are many other [questions about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639144/why-does-react-warn-against-an-contenteditable-component-having-children-managed) on Stack Overflow if you'd like to learn more.